# Memcached cache doesn't flush

Tags: centos, memcached

I would like to flush the memcached cache keys and values on my centos server.

I have tried the telnet approach by telnetting to the port and then issuing: flush_all

It doesn't work an my values are still cached.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: What is the "this" you are trying to accomplish exactly? What is the problem you are trying to solve? The `flush_all` command doesn't remove anything from the cache. It just marks the entries invalid.

Comment: You could just restart the daemon

Comment: from the memcached documentation: `This command does not pause the server, as it returns immediately. It does not free up or flush memory at all, it just causes all items to expire.` If you want to actually free it, you will have to restart the service. `sudo service memcached restart`

Answer (score 4):

Mark all items as stale (it will not clean the cache itself)

```
echo flush_all | telnet 127.0.0.1 11211
```

Perform dump, it will clean the stale items (but it may not deallocate memory)

```
/usr/share/memcached/scripts/memcached-tool 127.0.0.1:11211 dump > /dev/null
```

You can check the cache usage by

```
/usr/share/memcached/scripts/memcached-tool 127.0.0.1:11211 display
```

Tested on memcache 1.4.13